# Django Saving new record, int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'QueryDict'

Tags: python, django

code sample corrected December 27, 2017
I'm using Django 1.11 and Python 2.7.13. I'm deploying on Google App Engine using Cloud SQL (MySQL 5.7) but the error happens in my local development environment.

I have a very simple app with 1 form that collects some data and tries to save it as a new record in the database. It works fine if I use the default form and CreateView like this:

```
# views.py
class SubjectCreate(CreateView):
    model = Subject
    fields = '__all__'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('subapp:index')
```

However, I want to customize the form (move fields around, use check boxes, etc.) To do this from what I can tell I can't use the default CreateView, etc. but have to write my own. So here's what I've done:

```
# models.py
class Subject(models.Model):
    subject_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    subject_field2 = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    ... whole bunch of other fields ...

    def __str__(self):
        return self.subject_date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M') + 
                self.subject_field2[:35] + "..."


#views.py
def createnewsubject(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        subject_form = NewSubjectForm(request.POST)
        if subject_form.is_valid():
            subject_data = Subject(request.POST)
            subject_data.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
    else:
        subject_form = NewSubjectForm()
    return render(request, 'subapp/subject_form.html',
            {'form': subject_form})


# forms.py
class NewSubjectForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Subject
        fields = "__all__"
```

When the code hits subject_data.save() I get

```
TypeError at /new/
int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'QueryDict'
```

When I look through the trace I see

```
self    <django.db.models.fields.AutoField: id>

value   <QueryDict: { ... dict with all my app data ... }>
```

So it sounds like Django is trying to use my form data as the primary key of the new record. But the primary key should be auto-generated.

I've beaten my head on this for weeks using Django doc, Stack Overflow posts, and Google. I'm getting nowhere. Please help?

Comment: In your model form you call the model `Consultation`, but the model you post is called `Subject`.

Comment: You definitely *can* use the CreateView, I don't know why you think you can't. Just set the `form_class` attribute to your custom form.

Comment: Thanks @Daniel Roseman. That's exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My original post had copy/paste errors making it look like I had confused Subject with Consultation. Thanks to those who pointed that out, but it wasn't my problem.

Based on the comment by @Daniel Roseman I got this to work:

```
#models.py
class Subject(models.Model):
    subject_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    subject_field2 = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    ... whole bunch of other fields ...



#views.py
class SubjectCreate(CreateView):
    model = Subject
    form_class = NewSubjectForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('subapp:index')



#forms.py
class NewSubjectForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Subject
        fields = ['subject_date', 'subject_field2', ... ]
        widgets = {'subject_field2': forms.RadioSelect()}



#subject_form.html
{% load static %}
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'subapp/style.css' %}" />
{% if error_message %}<p><strong>{{ error_message }}</strong></p>{% endif %}
<form action="" method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
<table>
{{ form.as_table }}
<br>
</table>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

I used the standard CreateView class to define the view. I used form_class to tell CreateView which form to use.

In the form I used ModelForm and I told it what fields to use with fields=[...]. I also specified a custom widget with widgets={...}.

Then the template form is simple.

I don't know if this is the best or even a "right" way to do it, but it works.

Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

```
class NewSubjectForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Subject
        fields = '__all__'
```

the model must be `Subject` not `Consultation`,

## views.py

```
def createnewsubject(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        subject_form = NewSubjectForm(request.POST)
        if subject_form.is_valid():
            subject_data = subject_form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
        else:
            return HttpResponse(subject_form.errors.as_text())
    else:
        subject_form = NewSubjectForm()
    return render(request, 'subapp/subject_form.html',
            {'form': consultation_form})
```

or

## views.py

```
class SubjectCreate(CreateView):
    form_class = NewSubjectForm
    template_name = 'create.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('subapp:index')
```